# How to change a property of a doodad during gameplay?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

Let assume that we have a doodad in the middle of the map, for example 'Rubble Wall 45' (named testwall_1) and also we created a triggers (called 'timer' and 'rotate') with the following action:

> Timer - Start (New timer) as a Repeating timer that will expire in 5.0 Game Time seconds
>
> Events: Timer - Any Timer expires

What action(s) we should attach to the trigger(s) so that we can rotate the doodad (testwall_1)?